# Errors creating OpenStack deployment with Autopilot

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm following the [guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot), I correctly reached step 6. Now when I perform (from MAAS node, ubuntu user):

ubuntu@maas-server:~$ /snap/bin/conjure-up --bootstrap-to juju

the procedure stops with the following error:

```
ubuntu@maas-server:~/.cache/conjure-up$ cat conjure-up.log
2017-06-05 15:18:29,066 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: LXD version: 2.14, Juju version: 2.1.3-xenial-amd64
2017-06-05 15:18:33,227 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Path is local filesystem, copying /snap/conjure-up/352/spells/landscape to /home/ubuntu/.cache/conjure-up/landscape
2017-06-05 15:18:33,234 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Pulling bundle for landscape-dense-maas from channel: stable
2017-06-05 15:20:52,635 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Performing bootstrap: conjure-up-maas-8ac maas/163.162.31.2
2017-06-05 15:20:52,638 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: bootstrap cmd: juju bootstrap maas/163.162.31.2 conjure-up-maas-8ac --config image-stream=daily --config enable-os-upgrade=false --default-model conjure-landscape-09c --to juju --bootstrap-series=xenial --credential conjure-up-maas-199 --debug
2017-06-05 15:20:53,432 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Failed to find cloud in list-clouds, attempting to read bootstrap-config
2017-06-05 15:20:54,685 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: handle bootstrap
2017-06-05 15:20:54,712 [ERROR] log.py:17 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: 15:20:52 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:63 running juju [2.1.3 gc go1.6.2]

15:20:52 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:64   args: []string{"juju", "bootstrap", "maas/163.162.31.2", "conjure-up-maas-8ac", "--config", "image-stream=daily", "--config", "enable-os-upgrade=false", "--default-model", "conjure-landscape-09c", "--to", "juju", "--bootstrap-series=xenial", "--credential", "conjure-up-maas-199", "--debug"}

15:20:52 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 cloud "maas" not found, trying as a provider name

15:20:52 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 interpreting "163.162.31.2" as the cloud endpoint

15:20:52 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:780 authenticating with region "" and credential "conjure-up-maas-199" ()

15:20:52 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:892 provider attrs: map[]

15:20:52 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 Adding contents of "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys

15:20:52 INFO  cmd cmd.go:141 Adding contents of "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" to authorized-keys

15:20:52 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:948 preparing controller with config: map[uuid:f122f3e5-53f1-400b-8316-143a5c924e86 enable-os-refresh-update:true ssl-hostname-verification:true automatically-retry-hooks:true default-series:xenial name:controller authorized-keys:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJDdn+4XdYKoOce3jJIXzGj9+h6kCNGvn5r64sw9iDRiEDxeyv+2UAbL3r26G5jZGCp9Ra3WzE31/Gqs+0niiglucjbgWjSl3MuTGbVmQuZBY8UsD5hXs/ywLaskIwQwBktkefgsTif7ao5SQFYva7Z9xGtBDMpDP9n4BqcEp/w02te5SvILmnL/GiGKwAWETOCEEh0VdYyfY5Ac4wERu0nm2BXHRRc0flUnsVSguoBQSmbXaBvJ6PnYLleS61wqWYEIeu3FK6uE9FVGw5wHTYF4GsyQMcwh567xvA8nOD0YGpSKN1ptThKJ1CU8Pm7BPhMMGa/R0pz1+FRlOJQ3ix juju-client-key

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCuqiI+RZE29T/jzfwlCaFyNNhx07gxpW+3nDHZpLeDZ8/7Cf1UECaIHWDcI82ZRxg6gvvp8iAwBceslr14coD87e/GYu1/+BksYDjw5eS8cvymTgeck5IJ+xjseHwjh6o3/kHwsBoHq6lI0Ci5Px0JfIvro76Bu84UXhvdj+/ln6KHXOgFuqnJs862O02b5IuAjP1bLDc4RlslrQ9zTPwQWVGBVLc7iMZi/P1Ty7rMl438MnUtVxhY5kun913rLjXCaZq402ryIKDmnSsxLRU6nt8l7ncnOFIb0SJItmQRh+4uOmtSvvl195eOtFFNW5oU1nO3QQVzrDUQ1jTJY0iz ubuntu@maas-server

 development:false ftp-proxy: apt-http-proxy: firewall-mode:instance disable-network-management:false https-proxy: test-mode:false image-metadata-url: agent-stream:released apt-ftp-proxy: logging-config: net-bond-reconfigure-delay:17 http-proxy: image-stream:daily agent-metadata-url: type:maas transmit-vendor-metrics:true apt-mirror: provisioner-harvest-mode:destroyed proxy-ssh:false resource-tags: ignore-machine-addresses:false no-proxy: enable-os-upgrade:false apt-https-proxy: logforward-enabled:false]

15:20:52 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:51 opening model "controller".

15:20:53 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:458 Authorization Error: Invalid API key.

15:20:53 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:459 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands/bootstrap.go:445: } {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap/prepare.go:99: } {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap/prepare.go:160: } {github.com/juju/juju/provider/maas/environ.go:290: } {github.com/juju/gomaasapi/controller.go:85: } {github.com/juju/gomaasapi/controller.go:677: } {github.com/juju/gomaasapi/controller.go:774: } {github.com/juju/gomaasapi/controller.go:798: } {github.com/juju/gomaasapi/client.go:123: } {ServerError: 401 OK (Authorization Error: Invalid API key.)}])

2017-06-05 15:20:54,735 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Showing dialog for exception: Juju failed to bootstrap: maas
2017-06-05 15:20:54,826 [DEBUG] log.py:14 - conjure-up/_unspecified_spell: Failed to find cloud in list-clouds, attempting to read bootstrap-config
```

Am I missing any important step? I'm pretty sure MAAS user API key is correct, I tried also with a brand new one with the same result.

MAAS server is configured to use a proxy, and it works like a charm. I also attempted to add `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` env variables in /etc/environment, excluding with `no_proxy` all MAAS IP addresses, but either with this additional configuration the process does not work.

Thanks in advance for any hint.